# Adding to a large number and return a non scientific notation number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add 1 to a large number and return a non scientific notation value:

```
(parseInt("1000198078902400000000000000") + 1).toLocaleString('fullwide', { useGrouping: false })
```

However, this returns the same 1000198078902400000000000000 value instead of 1000198078902400000000000001 and I cannot figure out why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Answer (score 1):

`1000198078902400000000000000` is greater than the [`max integer value javascript can represent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER#:%7E:text=MAX_SAFE_INTEGER%20constant%20represents%20the%20maximum,larger%20integers%2C%20consider%20using%20BigInt%20.) which is 2<sup>53</sup> - 1 that is equal to `9007199254740991`.

You can use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to get the desired output. `BigInt` can represent numbers that are larger than 2<sup>53</sup> - 1.

```js
let num = BigInt("1000198078902400000000000000");
num += 1n;
console.log(num.toLocaleString('fullwide', { useGrouping: false }));
```

Comment: This returns the wrong number `1000198078902400000000000001`.

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei how is it wrong? What number did you expect?

Comment: I see. I missed the `+= 1n` :-)